# kendoGrid footerTemplate is giving me an error

Tags: telerik, kendo-grid

We have an ASP.Net Core application.

On my default.cshtml, I am populating a kendoGrid with data. The data displays fine.

But, I am trying to sum a column of the data in the footerTemplate. However, I keep getting this error: "**Uncaught ReferenceError: sum is not defined at footerTemplate**"

Below is my pseudo code. What am I doing wrong?

```
......UI
<div class="card-body">
@*GRID*@
<div id="my-grid"></div>
</div>
 ......


 $("#my-grid").kendoGrid({
data: [],
pageSize: 20,
schema: {
    model: {
        fields: {
            customerName: { type: "string" },
            sales: { type: "number" },
            .....
           }
        }
    },
dataBound: function (e) {
},
height: 650,
sortable: true,
//aggregate: [
//    { field: "sales", aggregate: "sum" }      //this didn't work either
//],
pageable: {
    numeric: true
},
groupable: false,
columns: [
    { field: "customerName", title: "Customer Name", width: "10%", footerTemplate: "Total: " },
    { field: "sales", title: "Sales Amount", width: "10%", attributes: { style: "text-align: right" }, 
        footerTemplate: "#=sum#",
        template: "#: kendo.toString(sales,'0.00') # " },
    .....
 ],
 })


function getData() {            //button click gets data to populate kendoGrid
...
axios.get(urlString)
.then(function (response) {
    var data = response.data
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
    { 
        data: data, 
        aggregate: [
            { field: "sales", aggregate: "sum" }
        ],
        pageSize: 12
    });
    var grid = $('#my-grid').data("kendoGrid");
    dataSource.read();
    grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
})
```

}